# how can 2+ user use git from a sudo account

Tags: git, sudo

We've just migrated from svn to git.  (bitbucket's codecloud git product)

We develop our code on a user we sudo to.
Using subversion, when we committed, it would ask us for our individual passwords and keep track of each "regular" linux user committing.

But when I clone the repo, only I can push to it.
If my workmate tries to, it asks for my password.

How can we both work on and git push the working copy to the server repo?

When I cloned it, I used the http prefix.  I've tried using the ssh prefix, but have not had success.  Perhaps our codecloud git hasn't been configured to allow ssh?

There MUST be other people in this situation...
The sudo account has access to certain sftp locations and our individual accounts are not allowed access to them.

Will we need to constantly:

git remote origin set-url https://username@server/project/repository.git

thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 2):

The typical solution is using different users (sharing an user has potential security concern), or at least checking out into different local repositories.

If you really want to use your current workflow. I think you can set different remotes

```
git remote add user1 https://user1@server/project/repository.git
git remote add user2 https://user2@server/project/repository.git
```

and do `git push user1` to specify which remote URL you want to push to.

Answer (score 0):

Put the username in your URL: `https://myusername@URL.com/soft.git.`

Make your `SSH key` available to the root user, because it will look under `/root/.ssh` instead of `/home/user/.ssh.`

Hope it helps..